# JMockit: Verifing a set of methods has not been called

Tags: jmockit

This question is about JMockit.
I know how to verify that a specific method has not been called for a class, for example:

```
new Expectations() {{
    writer.writeString(anyString); times = 0;
}};
```

Now, my writer has a bunch of methods called writeString, writeBoolean, writeArray, etc, and I want to verify that none of them has been called. Is it possible to do so using some kind regex/method name matching?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve that with the `FullVerifications` class. Something like:

```
@Test
public void myTest(@Mocked final Writer writer)
{
    codeUnderTest.doSomething(writer);

    new FullVerifications(writer) {{
        // Expected calls verified here.
        // Calls not expected will cause an "unexpected invocation" if detected.
    }};
}
```